# In Akka, is it possible to check what an UntypedActor's current message loop implementation is set to?

Tags: java, akka

I've been writing some tests and was wondering if it is possible to perform an assertion to ensure that an UntypedActor's current message loop implementation has been "hot swapped" as expected as described here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/untyped-actors.html#hotswap.

So for example, if I pass my actor a message it will handle the message and when complete change it's behaviour by executing the following:

```
getContext().become(initialising);
```

I want to be able to write an assertion such as:

```
assertEquals(initialising, testActor.currentBehaviour);
```

Or even, just verify that getContext().become(initialising) was executed.

Is this something that is currently possible via the Akka test kit?

I'm aware I could pass another message of a type expected by the new implementation to test this, but before going down that route I just wanted to check if there's a simpler approach such as a feature or alternative I'm missing.

Comment: Your best bet honestly is to pass in a message that would be handled differently by the new receive impl and then assert accordingly.  Anything else is really hackish IMO.